# Where to publish Provider Hosted app's web application?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, publishing, provider-hosted-app

I am confuse in provider hosted app's publish folder.

My questions are :

1. Can I publish provider hosted web application to any online server or I have to use only SharePoint online(Windows Azure) or Office 365 to publish my Web Application?
2. If I can publish my web application project to any online server how can I get the Client Id and Client Secret for that?
3. How can I create certificate for my app which I want to publish for SharePoint office app store?

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance...!

Comment: Down voters please do comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can host your provider hosted web application either on Windows Azure or your own server. The definition of provider-hosted app its self tells that you bring your hosting infrastructure for your application. Well if you have Azure subscription use it or use your  own hosting environment.
2. Clint Id and Client Certificate are not obtained from the web application you are hosting it is obtained from "/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx” your SharePoint site.

   [Refer my blog for more details on provider-hosted app](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/How-to-creating-Provider-hosted-apps-for-SharePoint-2013.aspx)
3. Sorry, I am not sure about obtaining certificate for windows store.

Comment: As you told me that any of the hosting environment, does that mean that I can publish my app to any of the .net server where my current asp.net site are hosted?

Comment: I haven't tried hosting the web application in my hosting environment yet but I hosted the web app in windows Azure and it worked fine for me. Windows Azure is nothing but a kind of hosting server only right? I think then you have to go for S2S authentication rather than oAuth

Comment: Ok.. Thank you for the answer... I will check for that. If you come to know any thing about that I can host web application to any server except Azure please let me know. It will really help full to me... Thank you again...

Comment: Sure I will make it!